# visibility of a class property defined on a custom Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: swift, properties, visibility, ios-frameworks

I'm creating a custom Framework used with my App Project.
I would to understand how I can access to a class property.

a piece of the class defined within the Framework has the code below:

```
public class MyDateField:MyTextField {
    private var _date:NSDate = NSDate()
    private var is2CloseKeyboard = false

    public var date:NSDate {
        get { return _date }
        set(newValue) {
            _date = newValue
            text = formatter.stringFromDate(_date)
        }
    }
..
}
```

now, when I try to access to that attribute (date)

```
self.detailItem.buyedAt = (textView as! MyDateField).date
```

Xcode report me an error:

> value of type 'MyDateField' has no member 'date'

could somebody give me some advice?

thanks

Comment: What is `MyTextField` ?

Comment: And what is the type of `buyedAt ` ?

Comment: buyedAt:NSDate, MyTextField: UITextField. could it related to the attribute's visibility?

Comment: What happens if you removed the `public` before `var date` ?

Comment: it had same behavior. I 'imported again' the library and updated the project configuration. now it works... thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Great ... Kindly if you solved your problem, write an answer and in two days you can accept your answer.  Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

**[ Solved ]**

the problem in my case was that I created the framework package for iOS device and I was building App Project with a simulator. I learned that it Must by synchronized of course...

I hope this could be helpful to somebody in order to avoid to spend time with this kind of 'issues' instead of coding :)